# child element should fill content no matter how much content is on the screen

Tags: html, css

In the example, I cannot get the `main` and `#root` elements to claim the remaining space when the expand button is clicked.

```css
html {
  border: 5px solid purple;
}

body {
  font-size: 19px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#root {
  max-width: 62rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border: 15px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function moreContent() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          document
            .querySelector("main div:last-child")
            .insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div>one</div>");
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <main>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="moreContent()">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `flex-growth` and `flex-shrink:1` that are not needed, with a simple `flex: 1`.

Also, you can set the minimum height of the root div to `100%` while asking it to `fit-content`

Then it should work.

```css
html {
  border: 5px solid purple;
}

body {
  font-size: 19px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#root {

    display: flex;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  height: fit-content;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    border: 15px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function moreContent() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          document
            .querySelector("main div:last-child")
            .insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div>one</div>");
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <main>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="moreContent()">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but now they don't fill the screen before expand is clicked and the yellow bordered div does not expand

Comment: The yellow do not extend, because in your exemple, the `one` div are appended OUTSIDE of the yellow main div (like I said above).

Comment: sorry, I've fixed that in the example now

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you set `height: 100%`, it detect the nearest parent's `height` property. And at the most upper parent, you limit its `height` to the screen `height`, which equals to 100%. So what you may want to do is to use `min-height` property, from the bottom child, to the upper parent.

```css
html {
  border: 5px solid purple;
}

body {
  font-size: 19px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#root {
  max-width: 62rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border: 15px solid yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function moreContent() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          document
            .querySelector("main div:last-child")
            .insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div>one</div>");
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <main>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>
          <button onclick="moreContent()">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```